# Possible sub pixel accuracy issue with svg rendering

Tags: html, graphics, svg

I need to create a line with an arrow head over it to indicate direction. But overlapping the arrow and the line looks nasty when you specify opacity. The solution seems easy enough, just split the arrow head and draw each head next to the line.

This works but for some reason the browser always leaves some space in between the line and the arrow head, which looks ugly.  Is this a known sub pixel accuracy issue with svg rendering?  Or am I missing some trick? Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" >
        <g stroke="blue" fill="blue" opacity="0.6" transform="rotate(30 200 200)">
            <path d="M 200 200 L 400 200" stroke-width="6"  />
            <path d="M 285 197 L 310 190 L 310 197"  />
            <path d="M 285 203 L 310 210 L 310 203"  />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't help, but can confirm I get a similar effect on Firefox and IE. If you use a stroke-width of 10 on the triangles the "line" moves down the arrowhead, confirming it's a real effect not an illusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually stumbled onto a solution for this. Turns out that you can do this by applying the opacity to the group, and just leave the individual items unset. This seems like the easiest solution, and does not bind us to markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" >
        <g stroke="blue" fill="blue" opacity="0.6" transform="rotate(30 200 200)">
            <path d="M 200 200 L 400 200" stroke-width="6"  />
            <path d="M 285 197 L 310 190 L 310 210 L 285 203"  />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using <marker>; to do this?

An easy workaround to fix this is to draw the shapes on top of each other and then use a filter to "patch" the opacity to a constant amount afterwards:

```
<filter id="opacity-patch">
   <feComponentTransfer>
       <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0.6 0.6"/>
   </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using markers. They are designed for this purpose.

The rough equivalent of your example would be the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
      <defs>
        <marker id="Triangle"
          viewBox="0 0 15 10" refX="7.5" refY="5" 
          markerUnits="strokeWidth"
          markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
          orient="auto" fill="blue">
          <path d="M 0 0 L 15 5 L 0 10 z" />
        </marker>
  </defs>
        <g stroke="blue" fill="blue" opacity="0.6" transform="rotate(30 200 200)">
            <path d="M 400 200 L 300 200 L 200 200" stroke-width="6" marker-mid="url(#Triangle)" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Markers can only be placed on path endpoints, so I had to split your line into two segments.  Assigning the marker using "marker-mid" ensures that it only appears at that new midpoint and not the start or end of the path.

Comment: We did try markers, but as you indicate you have to split the line into segments which we would prefer not to do.